# Access a static property of a generic class?

Tags: .net, generics

I use a `Height` for all the `Foo`s members. Like this

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    public static int FoosHeight;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Foo<???>.FoosHeight = 50; // DO I Set "object" here?
    }
}
```

The same situation is in VB.NET.

Comment: what is wrong with your eyes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd have to put some generic type parameter in there. That being said, I'll sometimes use some kind of inheritance scheme to get this functionality without having to put in the generic type parameter.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static int FoosHeight;
}

public class Foo<T> : Foo
{
   // whatever
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Foo.FoosHeight = 50; // DO I Set "object" here?
    }
}
```

That being said, this will keep the same FoosHeight regardless of the generic type parameter passed into `Foo<T>`.  If you want a different value for each version of `Foo<T>`, you'll have to pick a type to put in that type parameter, and forget the inheritance scheme.

Comment: Yes, it should.  Same general idea, just rewrite it in VB.NET.  Any online code converter should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify a type, such as

```
Foo<int>.FoosHeight = 50;
```

or

```
Foo<Bar>.FoosHeight = 50;
```

but each is separate.  `Foo<int>.FoosHeight` is not related to `Foo<Bar>.FoosHeight`.  They're effectively two separate classes with two distinct static fields.  If you want the value to be the same for all Foo<> then you need a separate place to store it like

```
FooHelper.FoosHeight = 50;
```

And FooHelper has no formal relationship with Foo<>.

Answer (score 2):

Each specific generic is it's own type, and therefore has it's own static variable.  So a `Foo<int>` would have a different static height member than a `Foo<string>`.  If you want that shared among all specific `Foo<T>` types, you need to implement that somewhere else.

If you really do just want to set the value for a `Foo<object>` type, than it's just that: `Foo<object>`.

Comment: I suppose the same situation will be with the Foo<object>, I mean Foo<object> will differ from Foo<string>

Comment: that is correct.  It's a different entity in the type system.